# Upgrading JIRA 5.1 to JIRA 6

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, tomcat7, jira

I am trying to upgrade my jira version from 5.1 to 6 in my test server. with windows(64) platform. So I downloaded jira 6 version with folder name as 
"atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone". then I strated jira with in command prompt
bin> start-jira.bat /fg it throws the below error. Please help me fix the error.[image]

Error:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.getDomain()Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: I think you should contact Atlassian support, and that this question is off topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks friend, there also I posted and waiting for the answers

Comment: Go to serverfault.com please.

Comment: let me try serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running on Tomcat 7. You are running on an earlier version (6 maybe?) where the CoyoteAdapter.getDomain() method does not exist.

I suggest an upgrade to 7.0.37 (or whatever the latest 7.0.x is when you read this).

Comment: My installed tomcat version is  7.0.37 only.